# How can i print the label of a subfloat inside a TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, subfloats

I'm laying out a few tikzpictures side by side (made with `pgfplots`, but I think it should not matter). I'm trying to use the `subfig` package to be able to reference single subfigures. Everything works ok, but I want `pgfplots` to layout the title to describe each subplot, so I need to:

1. Forbid the `subfig` package from printing the caption (note that even without an explicit `\caption` command, I get an empty caption but the counter is printed anyway)
2. Typeset the current subfigure number inside the tikz code (specifically in the title attribute of the `axis` environment, but the place could be arbitrary)
3. Being still able to reference single subfigures from the outside (i.e. where do I put the `\label` command?)

Here is a sketch of the code I have right now.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \subfloat[]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (0,0) {How do I typeset (and advance) the subfigure counter here?};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \quad
    \subfloat[]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (0,0) {How do I typeset (and advance) the subfigure counter here?};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{How to avoid this to print the counter even when I don't invoke this command?}
    }
  }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do this trick?

Comment: Do you have any code on the offering?

Comment: I thought about posting code, but I don't have anything more than the standard way of using subfig, with arbitrary tikzpictures inside the subfigures. I thought that would not be so useful. Would it be better to add something like that to the question?

Comment: The code goes a long way for those who try to answer. Starting from scratch is pain and you won't get to-the-point answers.

Comment: Why are you even using subfloats of subfigs?  \captionof{subfigure} is all you need, and maybe a few \hfil s.

Comment: @HarishKumar I've edited the question with the sample code.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't know `\captionof{subfigure}`, can you elaborate please?

Comment: It's from the caption package.  \captionof{} will create a caption for any type of float (more precisely, a counter) anywhere.  There is also \thesubfigure, but that won't increment the counter or show up in the list of figures.

Comment: Nice. It doesn't work, though. If I put that command inside the tikzpicture environment (just a node's label for example) I get an errore `You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.` plus a lot of other errors about missing numbers treated as zero.

Comment: @gigabytes You have to use `text width` as in `\node[text width=2cm] (0,0) {\captionof{subfigure}{}};`

Comment: That works, but now how do I do the same in the title attribute of a pgfplots axis environment?

Comment: `\pgfplotsset{every axis title/.append style={text width=2cm}}` and then `title={\captionof{subfigure}{some caption}}` Don't forget to load `caption` and `subcation` both.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have described how to do this with `\captionof`, here is a different approach with `\phantomsubcaption` from the `subcaption` package. `\phantomsubcaption` is useful for example if you have generated a figure with sub-figure labels included in the graphic, but it can also be used in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\newcommand\MakeLabel[1]{\phantomsubcaption\label{#1}\subref{#1})}
\begin{document}
In figure~\ref{fig:1} there is subfigure \ref{suba} and \ref{subb}.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4cm,title={\MakeLabel{suba} Subfigure a.}]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4cm,title={\MakeLabel{subb} Subfigure b.}]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption for entire figure.}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```