# Tikzpicture: How to caption with multiple axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions

Is there a way to caption multiple axes with tikzpicture? I don't want to use subfigures since each axis (and its corresponding figure) is connected via an arrow to another axis.

I have something similar to this:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} %axis 1
<code for plot here>
\draw node (bar1) at (some_coordinates){};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ %axis 2
xshift = 3in
]
<code for plot here>
\draw node (bar2) at (some_coordinates) {};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ %axis 3
xshift = 3in,
yshift = -3in,
]
<code for plot here>
\draw node (bar3) at (some_coordinates) {};
\end{axis}

\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed] (bar1) -- (bar2);
\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed] (bar2) -- (bar3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Is it possible to add a caption to each axis?

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? If not, can you comment on (one of) them to say what's missing? If one of them did solve it fully, consider accepting it, by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple axes environments are hard to connect, but at least you could use a `groupplot` by loading the `groupplots` library. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=7cm,width=7cm]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\draw node (bar1) at (1,0){bar1};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\draw node (bar2) at (1,2){bar2};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\draw node (bar3) at (1.5,1){bar3};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed](bar1)--(bar2);
\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed](bar2)--(bar3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want actual numbered captions, you can use `\captionof` in a node placed below the axis. You can have subfigure numbering if you prefer that, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250032/586

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.style={width=7cm}]
\begin{axis}[name=axis1] %axis 1
\addplot {rnd};
\node (bar1) at (1,1){};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ %axis 2
xshift = 3in,
name=axis2
]
\addplot {rnd};
\node (bar2) at (1,1) {};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ %axis 3
xshift = 3in,
yshift = -3in,
name=axis3
]
\addplot {rnd};
\node (bar3) at (1,1) {};
\end{axis}

\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed] (bar1) -- (bar2);
\draw [->,thick,color=red,dashed] (bar2) -- (bar3);

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=7cm,align=left}]
\node [below] at (axis1.south) {\captionof{figure}{First caption}};
\node [below] at (axis2.south) {\captionof{figure}{Second caption}};
\node [below] at (axis3.south) {\captionof{figure}{Third caption}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]